# C++ Compiler Error: No instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and have no clue why I'm told by the compiler that there's "no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocatorstd::string]" matches the argument list" when compiling the following code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "turpentine and turtles";
    std::vector<char> vowels = { 'a','e','i','o','u' };
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < vowels.size(); j++) {

            if (input[i] == vowels[j]) {

                result.push_back(input[i]);

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The type `input[i]` is `char`, not `std::string`.

Comment: `std::vector<char> result;` should do, depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: you are pushing a char to a vector of strings